# Custom choicegroup in J2ME Canvas

Tags: canvas, java-me, midp, lcdui

In my application, I have to add the choicegroup on Canvas.Is there any method to draw a choicegroup on canvas?
Is there any solution to make a custom choicegroup and implement it on canvas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MIDP 2 [lcdui](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/package-summary.html) API does not allow [ChoiceGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/ChoiceGroup.html) to be placed within [Canvas](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Canvas.html).

Being a subclass of [Item](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Item.html), ChoiceGroup can be only within [Form](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Form.html) objects.

- <sup>The closest you probably can get to it is to design your own custom object implementing [Choice](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/Choice.html) - the same interface as ChoiceGroup. To have such an object within Canvas, you would have to write your own, custom code for rendering its contents (size, fonts, alignment, wrapping etc) and to handle user events such as traversal, selection, and maybe something similar to item [commands and listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/ItemCommandListener.html) as well as [state and listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/ItemStateListener.html) if you need these.</sup>

Comment: gnat:: Do you have a sample code for making the custom ChoiceGroup and implementing it on the canvas. I searched a lot on the internet, but can't get the answer of my question.

Comment: @Karan it's quite unlikely that you'll find it - this would be too effort consuming to implement and test and the gain would be questionable at best. Consider other ways to meet your application requirements - whatever these are, I doubt these are stated as `implement choicegroup on canvas` - end users wouldn't bother how it's done internally